# Should my healthy, flower-covered eggplant be producing fruit yet?

Tags: vegetables, fruits, eggplant

I have one eggplant plant that I planted about 2 months ago. It is about 4 feet tall and has a large number of flowers. Should it have started to bear fruit?

I live on the Gulf Coast in Texas.

[image]

Comment: Cherie, welcome! Have some of the flowers fallen off or are they new? While you wait for answers, please take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about the site and the Stack Exchange system.

Comment: What is your pollinator situation like? You might want to get out there with a paintbrush...

Comment: And how's the temperature range at the moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if it's anything like the varieties we grew (commercially, in a hothouse), looking at the size of the plant it should have started bearing fruit. Do you know which variety you are growing?

There are a few possibilities why it might not be getting fruit, potentially including lack of a pollinator, although many varieties are, I believe, self-pollinating; and weather extremes. I've not seen it, but plants don't like temperatures above 30c/86f or so.

You might also want to prune the tree back drastically, which sends a signal to it to produce more fruit and will provide better yields.